# How can I use INetwork in Xamarin Forms XLabs?

Tags: networking, xamarin, cross-platform, xlabs

I am having a problem using INetwork from XLabs.Platform. I am getting System.NullReferenceException.  I am not sure if the problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060996/xamarin-using-geolocation-from-xlabs-sample) where I need to initialize INetwork.  However, because I am very new to Xamarin I have no idea how to set up the IOC container. I'd like to this in a completely cross-platform way (I'd like to avoid putting platform specific code if I can avoid it).  Thanks!!

Code:

```
using XLabs.Ioc;
using XLabs.Platform;
...
namespace XXX
{
   class XXX
    {
    public static bool isOnline()
    {

        var networkservice = DependencyService.Get<XLabs.Platform.Services.INetwork>();
        var status = networkservice.InternetConnectionStatus();
        return (
            (status.Equals(XLabs.Platform.Services.NetworkStatus.ReachableViaCarrierDataNetwork))
            || (status.Equals(XLabs.Platform.Services.NetworkStatus.ReachableViaWiFiNetwork))
            || (status.Equals(XLabs.Platform.Services.NetworkStatus.ReachableViaUnknownNetwork)));
    }

}

}
```

PS The documentation for using XLabs.Platform is out of date. The (apparently) previously functioning Reachability interface doesn't work anymore. Thinking about using [this](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Connectivity) instead.  [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/870548/Xamarin-forms-Check-network-connectivity-in-iOS-an) is an approach that requires cross platform code.  [Not going to use this](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/ReachabilitySample) as the author himself disses the approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if there is any Internet Connection,  I would suggest to use [Connectivity Plugin](https://components.xamarin.com/view/connectivityplugin) (Xamarin Component).  After adding the Xaamrin Component you can check if an internet connection is avaliable from PCL/Shared project like below

```
if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
{ // Make API call here 
} 
else 
      DisplayAlert("Connectivity Issue", "Please Connect to a Network", "OK") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You fill the ioc by adding this attribute:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(NameOfClassImplementingAnInterface))]
```